# Select from different tables using CONDITION using PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have a table with info that I want

```
TABLE_1
id
name
```

And a lot of other tables with the same type of data

```
TABLE_x
id
order

TABLE_y
id
order
```

...

```
TABLE_z
id
order
```

**What I want**: depending on the name from **TABLE_1** I want to acess the att order of other table.

Example:

```
TABLE_1
name = x
```

I want to access TABLE_x and check the order.
But if

```
TABLE 1
name = z
```

I want to access TABLE_z etc.

I thought about this piece:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1
INNER JOIN (
CASE (SELECT name FROM TABLE_1) 
WHEN 'x' THEN TABLE_x on TABLE_1.id=TABLE_x.id
WHEN 'y' THEN TABLE_y on TABLE_1.id=TABLE_y.id
WHEN 'z' THEN TABLE_z on TABLE_1.id=TABLE_z.id)
```

I can't use the case statement in here.

Need your help!

Comment: We are not a code writing service. Please refer to [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you tried to do any research? What have you tried? Questions here should have a clear problem/question, with research shown, and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0):

*I don't recommend what immediately follows*, but look closely at one possible solution:

```
-- NOT RECOMMENDED...
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT MIN(name) name FROM table_1
)
SELECT table_x.ordr FROM t1 JOIN table_x ON ('x' = t1.name)
UNION ALL
SELECT table_y.ordr FROM t1 JOIN table_y ON ('y' = t1.name)
UNION ALL
SELECT table_z.ordr FROM t1 JOIN table_z ON ('z' = t1.name)
/
```

If you think about what the database needs to do to satisfy that query, you'll realize it's a lot of individual queries, with at most 1 of them returning data.  *That could be a lot of work*, which is why it's not recommended.  You're likely much better off running an initial query against table_1, with the result driving the target of a subsequent query.  With sqlplus, you might opt for something like:

```
COLUMN name NEW_VALUE name NOPRINT
SELECT MIN(name) name FROM table_1
/
SELECT ordr FROM table_&&name
/
```

Do give some thought to error situations, such as when the name from query 1 doesn't match any existing table, or if there are no rows in table_1.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!! I will check that.